# How to style images in a list with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, list

I'm trying to make all the images I have in a list the same size and remove the bullet that gets placed beside them.

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<ul id = "imageList">
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie1.jpg' alt="Dunkirk"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie2.jpg' alt="Kong: Skull Island"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie3.jpg' alt="The Big Sick"> </li> 
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie4.jpg' alt="The Lovers"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie5.jpg' alt="Everybody Loves Somebody"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie6.jpg' alt="Happy End"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie7.jpg' alt="Okja"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie8.jpg' alt="Cars 3"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie9.jpg' alt="Despicable Me 3"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie10.jpg' alt="Baby Boss"> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: li{list-style: none; } 
width:50px; height:50px; this in img tag.
That's it.

Comment: Such questions are pretty trivial, I recommend you to kindly go through [W3 School CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) if you just started CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I set the hardcoded values as squares because I don't know what your actual images look like.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul id = "imageList">
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie1.jpg' alt="Dunkirk"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie2.jpg' alt="Kong: Skull Island"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie3.jpg' alt="The Big Sick"> </li> 
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie4.jpg' alt="The Lovers"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie5.jpg' alt="Everybody Loves Somebody"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie6.jpg' alt="Happy End"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie7.jpg' alt="Okja"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie8.jpg' alt="Cars 3"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie9.jpg' alt="Despicable Me 3"> </li>
    <li> <img src='../img/Movie10.jpg' alt="Baby Boss"> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nothing I seem to do changes the images at all, not even the bullet point.

Comment: @Joshm102 Are you using WordPress? Is the website live? Can you post it here? What browser are you using? What browser version is it? What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Joshm102 If this doesn't work for you then you're probably loading another stylesheet that is causing your changes not to have any effect...

Answer (score 1):

I use of `!important` for override on each other style.

```css
#imageList {
    list-style: none !important;;
}

#imageList img {
    width: 50px !important;;
    height: 50px !important;;
}
```

```html
<ul id = "imageList">
    <li> <img src='http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg' alt="Dunkirk"> </li>
    <li> <img src='http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg' alt="Kong: Skull Island"> </li>
    <li> <img src='http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg' alt="The Big Sick"> </li> 
    <li> <img src='http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg' alt="The Lovers"> </li>
</ul>
```